# Screen Transition effect using UIView.animate

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have an app with various screens. I have a next button and a previous button on every screen. On click of the next button I'll be showing my next screen. Right now I'm showing my next screen by making use of UIView.animate() which is simply replacing my present screen with next screen. It doesn't give/produce any animation effect while screen transition. On click of next button, I want the next screen to look like coming/presented from right side. How can I achieve such transition effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a navigation view controller and set it as the initial view controller for that series of views.

or

```
let newView  = sampleStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewViewController") as! NewViewController 

self.present(newView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I'm not making use of a navigation view controller in my present design. My design is like a common view controller at the start which will have a container view. All the next screens are replaced in place of container view. I don't want to change my design now. I'm looking to get it done using UIView.animate()

Comment: edited my answer to accomplish this programmatically.

Comment: @ShaneShelton Please put the code inside a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement simple protocol, and use it for your view:

```
protocol PresentedAsPush {
    func presentLikeAPush()
}

extension UIView: PresentedAsPush {

    func presentLikeAPush() {
        self.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.width, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5) { [weak self] in // configure slide animation duration, and handler, if you need
            guard let wrappedSelf = self else { return }
            wrappedSelf.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: wrappedSelf.bounds.width, height: wrappedSelf.bounds.height)
        }
    }

}
```

Code of pushing:

```
func pushView() {
     let blueView = UIView(frame: view.bounds)
     blueView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
     view.addSubview(blueView)
     blueView.presentLikeAPush()   
}
```

In Your case you just use:

```
toController.view.presentLikeAPush()
```

Also You might implement handler for presentLikeAPushMethod, and return animation completion block in it, and do what you need after animation (remove old controller etc)

Also You can use a constraints instead of a frame.
Adding full code:

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        let redVc = RedViewController()
        addChild(redVc)
        view.addSubview(redVc.view)
    }

}

class RedViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        let pushButton = UIButton()
        view.addSubview(pushButton)
        pushButton.setTitle("push", for: .normal)
        pushButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50)
        pushButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pushButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc private func pushButtonPressed() {
        guard let parent = parent else { return }

        let blueVc = BlueViewController()
        parent.addChild(blueVc)
        parent.view.addSubview(blueVc.view)

        blueVc.view.presentLikeAPush(fromController: self)
    }

}

class BlueViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

}

protocol PresentedAsPush {
    func presentLikeAPush(fromController: UIViewController)
}

extension UIView: PresentedAsPush {

    func presentLikeAPush(fromController: UIViewController) {
        self.frame = CGRect(x: bounds.width, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: { [weak self] in
            guard let wrappedSelf = self else { return }
            wrappedSelf.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: wrappedSelf.bounds.width, height: wrappedSelf.bounds.height)
        }) { (completed) in
            fromController.view.removeFromSuperview()
            fromController.removeFromParent()
            fromController.willMove(toParent: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you once clearly explain the 2 methods that you have written, I didn't get it completely. You have written a function pushView() which is not getting called from anywhere.

Comment: @KunduriRaj, pushView () is an example of a method for explaining how to use presentLikeAPush (), you don't need it

Comment: @ idev.agg.mf Can you look at my updated code once. I tried removing the old controller in my completed block but still  the old controller is getting overrided with the new controller.